# Reading Excel cells takes a lot of time

Tags: c#, excel, performance

I have an Excel file which it has 360 rows and 181 columns (65,160 cells). Most of the cells are empty and I just want to save non-empty cells.

The Main problem is, when I run my code, it takes about six minutes to process all of the cells and this procedure should be done for 3,000 Excel files. I wrote this code in my form_load event:

```
        Excel.Application xlapp;
        Excel.Workbook xlwb;
        Excel.Worksheet xlws;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlapp = new Excel.Application();
        xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlws = (Excel.Worksheet)xlwb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        Int32 last_row = Convert.ToInt32(xlws.UsedRange.Rows.Count);
        Int32 last_column = Convert.ToInt32(xlws.UsedRange.Columns.Count);

        label1.Text = "";

        for ( j = 1; j <=last_row; j++)
        {
            for ( i = 1; i <= last_column; i++)
            {
                if (xlws.Cells[j,i].value != null)
                {
                    label1.Text = label1.Text + xlws.Cells[j, i].value.ToString();
                }
            }
            label1.Text += "\n";
        }

        xlwb.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlapp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlws);
        releaseObject(xlwb);
        releaseObject(xlapp);
```

and this is my releaseObject function:

```
        private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {

        try
        {System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
         obj = null;}

        catch (Exception ex)
        {obj = null;
         MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());}

        finally

        {GC.Collect();}

    }
```

Is there any way to reduce the wasted time?

Comment: Accessing Excel (mainly with something as comprehensive as Interop) is very slow. 6 mins sounds too much time though. If all what you want is reading cell values, it would be better to rely on a faster approach (e.g., convert it to CSV and access it as a text file).

Answer (score 1):

My company has several internal tools that access Excel workbooks.  And there are several ways to do so.  Treating the workbook as a data source and querying it with OleDb works well.  In my experience it is much faster than using Excel Automation.  Here is some sample code that comes from an existing project.  It queries a workbook that has 2 spreadsheets, one for Metric units and one for English (Imperial) units.  Hope it helps...

```
// get Excel file that should be imported
string strFilePath = "";
this.openFileDialog.Title = "Select Excel File For Importing";
this.openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;";
this.openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
this.openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
this.openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
strFilePath = this.openFileDialog.FileName;
this.txtExcelFileName.Text = this.openFileDialog.FileName;

string strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;\"";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapterExcel = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oledbConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
DataTable tblEnglishTab = new DataTable("English");
DataTable tblMetricTab = new DataTable("Metric");
DataSet datasetExcelData = new DataSet();

oledbConnection.Open();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmdselect = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();

try
{
    cmdselect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [English$A1:N10000]";
    cmdselect.Connection = oledbConnection;
    dataAdapterExcel.SelectCommand = cmdselect;
    dataAdapterExcel.Fill(tblEnglishTab);
    datasetExcelData.Tables.Add(tblEnglishTab);
}    
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please verify the Excel file type.\nUnable to locate the English worksheet in the specified file."Excel Import", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}    
try
{
    cmdselect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Metric$A1:N10000]";
    cmdselect.Connection = oledbConnection;
    dataAdapterExcel.SelectCommand = cmdselect;
    dataAdapterExcel.Fill(tblMetricTab);
    datasetExcelData.Tables.Add(tblMetricTab);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please verify the Excel file type.\nUnable to locate the Metric worksheet in the specified file.", "Excel Import", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
oledbConnection.Close();
dataAdapterExcel = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The String object is immutable. Every time you use one of the methods
>   in the System.String class, you create a new string object in memory,
>   which requires a new allocation of space for that new object.

Use `StringBuilder` when populating data from excel, then put it into `label1.Text`

Here is example:

```
label1.Text = "";

StringBuilder excelContent = new StringBuilder();

for ( j = 1; j <=last_row; j++)
{
    for ( i = 1; i <= last_column; i++)
    {
        if (xlws.Cells[j,i].value != null)
        {
            excelContent.Append(xlws.Cells[j, i].value.ToString());
        }
    }
    excelContent.Append("\n");
}

label1.Text = excelContent.ToString();
```

You can read more about `StringBuilder` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i have tested your suggest but it still takes pretty much time to do all loops.its not about StringBuilder. its about the amount of cells and loops.

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHajiRamezanAli As said above: accessing Excel is slow (mainly with Interop), if you just want to read all the cells, you wouldn't need to access it as an Excel file (becuase you are not using all the associated special Excel features), but as a mere CSV file (text file).

Comment: @varocarbas I didn't get it. `label1.Text + "some text"` is creating new object over and over and assigning it to `label1.Text`. Also marking previous object for GC collectiong. I am saying something wrong ?

Comment: @varocarbas then you mean there is no way to make it faster? would it be faster if they were in a text file?thanks

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHajiRamezanAli There are always ways to make things faster. I am saying that for what you are doing it would be better to treat it as CSV; this is an automatic conversion as far as CSV is a supported format by Excel. You store the workbook as CSV and access it as text.

Comment: @AramKocharyan I am coming back to properly state my position (because I have read quite a few ideas on your same line of thought during the last days). Assignation/reinstantiation of a single variable (even of 1000) is not relevant at all from a macroscopic point of view. Things like `StringBilder` might be the best approach for different reasons, but not for delivering a better (and actually noticeably) improvement in performance/memory. Not understanding this point would be like thinking that coke light + whisky has less calories than water...

Comment: ... That is: using any kind of string concatenation cannot be seen as a way to improve performance (or memory management). You might fully optimise a given code without even caring about this issue. In any case and as said the other day, knowing a bit about the underlying reality is not a bad thing (as long as you apply the ideas in the right context). The inmutable character of the string type is a bit tricky (in .NET and everywhere) and provokes memory re-allocations in quite a few scenarios (other than the ones I mentioned in my previous comments), but this happens at a veeeeery tiny level.